# Firestore Emulator fails to start when run inside Docker

Tags: java, firebase, docker, google-cloud-firestore, alpine-linux

I am running a docker image based on `alpine` that has `nodejs` and `openjdk8` installed.  After I successfully install `firebase-tools` via `npm` and I try to start the firestore emulator using this command:

```
firebase serve --only firestore
```

I get the following error:

```
    ⚠  firestore: Exception in thread "main"
    ⚠  firestore: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind

    ⚠  firestore:   at io.grpc.netty.NettyServer.start(NettyServer.java:256)
            at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:167)
            at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:81)
            at io.gapi.emulators.grpc.GrpcServer.start(GrpcServer.java:151)
            at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.firestore.CloudFirestore.main(CloudFirestore.java:69)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Protocol family unavailable
            at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
            at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
            at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)

    ⚠  firestore:   at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:130)
            at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:562)
            at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1358)
            at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:501)
            at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:486)
            at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1019)
            at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:258)
            at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:366)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)

    ⚠  firestore:   at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:474)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I tried setting the `JAVA_OPTS` as follows:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true"
```

But I still get a similar error:

```
    ⚠  firestore: Exception in thread "main"
    ⚠  firestore: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind
            at io.grpc.netty.NettyServer.start(NettyServer.java:256)
            at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:167)
            at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:81)
            at io.gapi.emulators.grpc.GrpcServer.start(GrpcServer.java:151)
            at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.firestore.CloudFirestore.main(CloudFirestore.java:69)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Protocol family unavailable
            at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
            at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
            at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
            at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:130)
            at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:562)
            at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1358)
            at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:501)
            at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:486)
            at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1019)
            at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:258)
            at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:366)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:474)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Has anyone seen this error and found a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is simple, though I must admit doesn't make much sense, is to run the JAR directly and not start it via the `firebase` tool.

```
java -jar $HOME/.cache/firebase/emulators/cloud-firestore-emulator-v1.3.0.jar --host=127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it trying to bind to an IPV6 address ? 
To use with a custom port with IPV4 with google cloud SDK:

```
gcloud beta emulators firestore start --host-port=127.0.0.1:8772
```

Or else, try to [enable IPV6](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ipv6/) on [you docker](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/ipv6/) ?

Comment: This worked for me, that's a good point about IPV6.